# Use same controller but pass a filter?

Tags: laravel

I have a resource for a feed:

```
Route::resource('feed', FeedController::class);
```

But I'd also like to have a way to show trending items. Something like `/feed/trending`.

I prefer the URL params to query string.

How can I set this up? I've considered:

```
Route::resource('feed/{trending?}', FeedController::class);
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function index($trending = null) {
    //check if trending is not null and filter results based in that
```

But if you do `/feed/trendingxyz` trending would be that specific value.

Is there a way to have a param that can route to the same resource controller, and in that resource controller check if results should be trending or not?

Answer (score 0):

you better use query string
in your controller check if have a request with trending key then show trendings:

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    if($request->has('trending')) {
        // do something with $request->input('trending') or something else you want
    }
```

Comment: I asked not to use query strings.

Comment: @panthro why not?